# how to insert csv.gz to table in clickhouse?

Tags: python, clickhouse

I created a table called `test_table` and I am trying to insert a `csv.gz` file data into it. My clickhouse db is running locally on a docker container with port 18123:8123. This is what I did using their python client:

```py
import clickhouse_connect
client = clickhouse.connect.get_client(host='localhost', port=18123)
stmt = f"""
    INSERT INTO test_table
    FROM INFILE 'data.csv.gz'
    COMPRESSION 'gzip' FORMAT CSV
"""
client.command(stmt)
```

but I get an error saying

```
clickhouse_connect.driver.exceptions.DatabaseError: :HTTPDriver for http://localhost:18123 returned response code 404)
DB::Exception: Query has infile and was send directly to server. (UNKNOWN_TYPE_OF_QUERY) (version 23.2.1.2537 (official build))
```

Any clue to what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> Query has infile and was send directly to server

It means INFILE queries supported by `clickhouse-client` command line utility.
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/interfaces/cli

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/insert-into#inserting-data-from-a-file

try to use python requests library with streaming mode and upload your file directly via HTTP interface

something like that

```py
import requests

url = "http://localhost:8123/?query=INSERT INTO test_table COMPRESSION 'gzip' FORMAT CSV"

# Local file path
file_path = "data.csv.gz"

# Open file as binary and send in chunks
with open(file_path, "rb") as file:
    # Set up request headers
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'}

    # Make the POST request to upload the file
    with requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=file, stream=True) as response:
        # Raise an exception if the response status is not 200 OK
        response.raise_for_status()

        # Print the response text
        print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Slach's answer using python request worked but I ended up using `clickhouse-client` in bash. Here's my solution:

```py
    def insert_file(
        filepath: str,
        tablename: str,
        exist_okay: bool=True,
        skip_first_line: int=1, 
        port: int=9000,
        max_partitions_per_insert_block=20000,
    ):        
        # input_format_csv_skip_first_lines is the number of rows 
        # to skip from the beginning of the file
        #
        # date_time_input_format is the format of the datetime
        # column. 'best_effort' means that the datetime column
        # will be parsed as a string and then converted to
        # datetime64(9) type
        #
        # compression is the compression type of the file
        # 
        # format is the format of the file
        bash_cmd = f"""
        clickhouse-client --port {port} \
        --input_format_csv_skip_first_lines {skip_first_line} \
        --date_time_input_format 'best_effort' \
        -q "INSERT INTO {tablename} \
            FROM INFILE '{filepath}'\
            SETTINGS max_partitions_per_insert_block={max_partitions_per_insert_block}"
        """
        print(bash_cmd)
        subprocess.call(bash_cmd, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Docs](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/insert-into#inserting-data-from-a-file) say

> This functionality is available in the command-line client and clickhouse-local.

So you can't use this kind of commands using Python client. But, the client has it's own way of insterting files ([docs](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/integrations/python#file-inserts))

```
import clickhouse_connect
from clickhouse_connect.driver.tools import insert_file

client = clickhouse_connect.get_client()
insert_file(client, 'example_table', 'my_data.csv',
            settings={'input_format_allow_errors_ratio': .2,
                      'input_format_allow_errors_num': 5})
```